# Vertically centering text on <a> tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons set up with my HTML so that they are all the same height, by using this CSS and HTML

```css
ul {
     display: table;
     padding: 0;
     width: 90%;
     margin: 5% auto;
     list-style-type: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 20vh;
    }
    li {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     margin-top: 15px;
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    li.third {
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
    }
    .ghost-button {
     color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
     border: 1px solid rgb(9, 82, 85);
     padding: 5px 5px;
     margin: auto;
     display: inline-block;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
    } 
    
    .third a {
     display: block;
     margin-left: 50%;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .ghost-button:hover, .ghost-button:active {
     color: #FFF;
     background-color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1A.php" class="ghost-button" >Check the newspaper classifieds
 for affordable pieces </a></li>
<li><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1B.php" class="ghost-button" >Check for garage sales within
 walking distance </a></li>
<li class="third"><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1C.php" class="ghost-button" >Do nothing</a></li>
</ul>
```

On my page the buttons don't overlap it is an issue with the snippet that I can't figure out. The snippet also has to be viewed full page, or the issue doesn't occur. Sorry for the issues it's my first time using a snippet.

I want to make the text vertically aligned and as you can see, unless I am using it wrong, `vertical-align: middle` isn't working.

Comment: Looks vertically centered on my screen. What browser are you using? Or maybe i don't understand the problem.

Comment: Did you click the link to open the snippet in the full page? the buttons get taller and the text remains at the top.

Comment: Yeah I viewed full screen, the buttons width expands but the text still looks centered. I am viewing in firefox. I will copy to a jsfiddle and look though. https://jsfiddle.net/srfp2c52/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex` on the links, and `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to center horizontally and vertically.

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20vh;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

li.third {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.ghost-button {
  color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
  border: 1px solid rgb(9, 82, 85);
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.third a {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.ghost-button:hover,
.ghost-button:active {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1A.php" class="ghost-button">Check the newspaper classifieds
 for affordable pieces </a></li>
  <li><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1B.php" class="ghost-button">Check for garage sales within
 walking distance </a></li>
  <li class="third"><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1C.php" class="ghost-button">Do nothing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the **display:inline-block** on .ghost-button to **display:inline-flex** and change the **vertical-align:middle** to **align-items:center**

The **align-items** is the vertical centering for flex boxes.  **justify-content** will handle horizontal alignment.

```css
ul {
     display: table;
     padding: 0;
     width: 90%;
     margin: 5% auto;
     list-style-type: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 20vh;
    }
    li {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     margin-top: 15px;
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    li.third {
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
    }
    .ghost-button {
     color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
     border: 1px solid rgb(9, 82, 85);
     padding: 5px 5px;
     margin: auto;
     display: inline-flex;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     align-items:center;
    } 
    
    .third a {
     display: block;
     margin-left: 50%;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .ghost-button:hover, .ghost-button:active {
     color: #FFF;
     background-color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a class="ghost-button" href="S1A.php" >Check the newspaper classifieds
 for affordable pieces </a></li>
<li><a class="ghost-button"  href="S1B.php">Check for garage sales within
 walking distance </a></li>
<li class="third"><a class="ghost-button" href="S1C.php" >Do nothing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flex; `vertical-align` property only ever worked for me if `display:table-cell` was applied.

```css
ul {
     display: table;
     padding: 0;
     width: 90%;
     margin: 5% auto;
     list-style-type: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 20vh;
    }
    li {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     margin-top: 15px;
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    li.third {
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
    }
    .ghost-button {
     color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
     border: 1px solid rgb(9, 82, 85);
     padding: 5px 5px;
     margin: auto;
     
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items:center;
    } 
    
    .third a {
     display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items:center;
     margin-left: 50%;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .ghost-button:hover, .ghost-button:active {
     color: #FFF;
     background-color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1A.php" class="ghost-button" >Check the newspaper classifieds
 for affordable pieces </a></li>
<li><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1B.php" class="ghost-button" >Check for garage sales within
 walking distance </a></li>
<li class="third"><a class="ghost-button" class="ghost-button" href="S1C.php" class="ghost-button" >Do nothing</a></li>
</ul>
```